# Passing Download complete Event with parameter to another class

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I have an application whose main window upon click of a button gives users an option to load a list of files in the cloud.

```
 Private Sub ImportCloudContent()
        Dim cloudForm As Form_CloudImport
        cloudForm = New Form_CloudImport()
        cloudForm.Show()
        cloudForm.populateDataGrid()

        AddHandler cloudForm._DownloadComplete, New EventHandler(AddressOf OpenProject)

        cloudForm.DownloadNotifier(FullPathOfContent)

    End Sub
```

Ideally I should be able to get the value of the *FullPathOfContent* variable and pass it onto Open Project, but I am not sure how to go about it.

In the new Window users can click and download the file they want. Below is the section of code that handles the download in the Form_CloudImport class :

```
   Private Async Sub Btn_download_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_download.Click

        Dim fileNameRows As DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection = datagridview_cloudContent.SelectedRows
        Dim fileName As String
        Dim fileType As String = Cloud.CONTENT
        Dim FullPathOfContent As String
        For Each fileNameRow As DataGridViewRow In fileNameRows
            fileName = fileNameRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString() & ".zip"
            Try
                FullPathOfContent = CloudToCCT(fileName, fileType)
            Catch ex As Exception
                CSMessageBox.ShowError("Content Import failed : ", ex)
            End Try
        Next
        Me.Close()
        DownloadNotifier(FullPathOfContent)
    End Sub
```

Once the download is complete, the main window needs to call some of its methods. I am new to VB and have created a custom event to facilitate this(again in the Form_CloudImport class)

```
Public Event _DownloadComplete(e As String)

Public Sub DownloadNotifier(FullPathOfContent As String)
    RaiseEvent _DownloadComplete(FullPathOfContent)
End Sub
```

According to what have read, once the download method is complete, it will fire the *DownloadNotifier* method, which will raise the *_DownloadComplete* event and the MainWindow should trigger the following events.

However, I receive the below errors in the MainWindow part of the code :

```
Value of type 'MainWindow.EventHandler' cannot be converted to 'Form_CloudImport._DownloadCompleteEventHandler'
```

and

```
'FullPathOfContent' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

This question seems to be very long but any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need the code `New EventHandler` when using the `AddHandler` keyword.  Giving it the `AddressOf` a method whose signature matches the event signature is enough. In this case, that means the `OpenProject` method should be declared `Sub OpenProject(e as String)`.

Comment: For the second error, you don't need the line `cloudForm.DownloadNotifier(FullPathOfContent)` in your main form.  The cloud form will raise the event on its own; as long as you've done `AddHandler`, you should do the the rest inside your handling method (`OpenProject`).

Comment: Thank you so much, looks like both my issues are fixed

Comment: That's a bad event in the first place. I suggest that you read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html) to learn the proper way to declare and raise a custom event.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you should create a type and event with proper names and signature and raise it properly.

```vb
Public Class CloudImportForm

    Public Event DownloadComplete As EventHandler(Of DownloadCompleteEventArgs)

    Protected Overridable  Sub OnDownloadComplete(e As DownloadCompleteEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent DownloadComplete(Me, e)
    End Sub

    '...

End Class


Public Class DownloadCompleteEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Sub New(contentPath As String)
        Me.ContentPath = contentPath
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property ContentPath As String

End Class
```

In that form, you would have code that performed a download and then raised that event.

```vb
'...

Dim contentPath = GetContentPath()

'Perform download here.

'Raise event.
OnDownloadComplete(New DownloadCompleteEventArgs(contentPath))
```

In your main form you would create and configure the download form, which includes handling the event, and then display it.

```vb
Dim cloudForm As New CloudImportForm

AddHandler cloudForm.DownloadComplete, AddressOf CloudImportForm_DownloadComplete
cloudForm.PopulateDataGrid()
cloudForm.Show()
```

The method you specify as the event handler should have the appropriate signature and it should retrieve the content path from the `e` parameter.

```vb
Private Sub CloudImportForm_DownloadComplete(sender As Object, e As DownloadCompleteEventArgs)
    Dim contentPath = e.ContentPath

    'Use contentPath here.
End Sub
```